# UltraLiteJ database on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

How do I install Sybase UltraLiteJ database on a BlackBerry?

Answer (score 2):

[Browsing StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371551/duplicate-definition-setting-up-ultralitej-blackberry-sample-project), I see there is a [tutorial from Sybase](http://dcx.sybase.com/1100en/ulj_en11/uj-tutorial-s-3972626.html).